# Which statement should be inserted independently to compile?

Tags: java, arraylist

One line of code should be included in the below program to compile successfully.

```
import java.util.*;

class Business { }
class Hotel extends Business { }
class Inn extends Hotel { }

public class Travel {
   ArrayList<Hotel> hotels() {
      // insert code here to compile
   }
}
```

Comment: you can return null or return new ArrayList()

Comment: What are your thoughts regarding your homework, besides : "let's see if someone else might do it for me"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a return statement, the simplest being:

```
return null;
```

Or throw an (unchecked) exception:

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

Or a statement which never completes, e.g.:

```
while (true);
```

Comment: This is a blatant "do my homework" request, with zero evidence that the OP tried himself. Such questions aren't appreciated here. Same goes for answers that just do that: his or her homework!

Comment: It's also factually inaccurate. You don't *need* a return statement.

Comment: @AndyTurner how else can you make it compile? I suppose it could throw an exception..

Comment: @wilmol you need either a statement which is guaranteed to complete abruptly, or one that is guaranteed never to complete.